# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom {m+n}{n}^{-1}=\frac{m}{m-1}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

> Proving $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom {m+n}{n}^{-1}=\frac{m}{m-1}$$

I'm not quite sure what to do with the sum of terms that combinations appear in denominators. I tried to solve the problem via splitting items, but failed.

But when I happened to see the following formula
$$
\int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^m\,dx= \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!}
$$
I got some idea as follows

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{m+n}{n}^{-1}
&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \, (m+n+1)\int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^m\,dx
\\ &=
\int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty (m+n+1)x^n \right) (1-x)^m \,dx
\\ &=
\int_0^1 \left( \frac{m+1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \right) (1-x)^m \,dx
\\ &=
(m+1)\int_0^1 (1-x)^{m-1} \,dx + \int_0^1 x (1-x)^{m-2} \,dx
\\ &=
\frac{m}{m-1}
\end{align}

I am looking forward to other methods or a more deep-going idea to solve this problem such as solving it via the property of gamma function, I guess. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your proof doesn´t appears on the duplicate question maybe you could added it there

Comment: @Nadide Thanks for reminding me of that. I'll do it later.